# What does "actinide" as an adjective means in this phrase:

Tags: meaning-in-context, word-meaning, adjectives

The following exerpt from a web-novel:

> A shaft of pure **actinide** destruction lanced forth from its outthrust palm (...)

[source](https://www.royalroad.com/fiction/21361/skyclad/chapter/335119/chapter-22-incineratus)

What does "actnide" means in this context?

Comment: The primary characteristic of all actinides is that they're ***radioactive***. So in your cited example it's just a (slightly creative) alternative to *radioactive destruction*.

Comment: This seems like an adequate answer ... why not make it an answer?

Comment: I don't know, seems pretty speculative. @Mindwin: did you look up this word? Please describe your difficulty applying the definitions you have found.

Comment: @FumbleFingers please post your comment as an answer.

Comment: @SamBC I was unable to find a source of this word as an adjective.

Comment: Its usual noun meaning is the f-block elements in group 7 of the periodic table (that immediately follow actinium). It can be used as an adjective with the same meaning, as one might find "actinide elements". It's a pretty unusual word, often absent from spellcheck dictionaries. I shall give my own suspicions as an answer.

Comment: @fred2, Mindwin: One good reason for me not posting my comment as an "Answer" is because (as I now see, thanks to SamBC) I was somewhat mistaken in my focus. The allusion is more to do with ***harsh / blinding light*** than radioactivity as such (in my now-revised opinion, which is of course just an opinion).

Answer (score 1):

I rather suspect that the author is simply misusing the word.

The **actinides** are the f-block elements of group 7 in the periodic table, so called because they come immediately after actinium. The elements share some characteristics, such as having largely incomplete f-shell electrons and being radioactive, but none of that is applicable here. After all, most radioactive elements aren't in the actinide grouping.

I suspect they actually meant ***actinic***. It's another scientific term, but one that has found great currency in certain types of fiction writing, especially in the set phrase '*actinic glare*'. Actinic light is usually bright and low-wavelength (blue-white).

It is most likely that the two words are related, but they mean very different things.

Comment: Indeed. I easily found examples like [*There was nothing in its brief actinic glare to tell him whether it was a government freighter from Earth or a **Venusian Fisheries** cargo collector in trouble.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22brief+actinic+glare%22) Particularly characteristic of sci-fi in the decades immediately following WW2, I feel. Etymologically, *actinide* and *actinic* are indeed related (as is the element *actinium*). The sci-fi usage probably gained traction through association with A-bombs.

Comment: Some of the examples I found were from the 30s, it's worth noting. In some circles it refers to light capable of stimulating a photochemical reaction.